# pycharm compound run in debug

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I'm using the `compound` feature in pycharm to run multiple configurations at once. I would like to run them in debug mode instead. All or some of them.

Is it possible? I can't find a way to tell pycharm I want to run a specific configuration in `debug` mode.

Comment: It does not seem possible.  You might try: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm